# TSQL LDAP query via Linked Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, active-directory

I have strange problem, I have 3 SQL Server 2012 with Sp1 instances, and on all of them, the versions are identical.

I am trying to query Active Directory services, on 2 of them this is working correctly, but one of them is throwing an error

> Cannot get the column information from OLE DB provider "ADsDSOObject" for linked server "ADSI_TEST".

If I don't use Active Directory Server Name in the query it works fine.

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Can you post the query?

Answer (score 0):

to query the active directory I use the procedure [xp_logininfo](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190369.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

> Requires membership in the sysadmin fixed server role or membership in
>   the public fixed database role in the master database with EXECUTE
>   permission granted.

I have been using the following script and it works fine for me:

```
SELECT @@SERVERNAME
--myserver

DECLARE @NTLogin nvarchar(128); 
SET @NTLogin = 'mycompany\person_or_group_I_want_to_check'

DECLARE @UserList TABLE (
         [Account Name] nvarchar(128),
         [Type] nvarchar(128),
         [Privilege] nvarchar(128),
         [Mapped Login Name] nvarchar(128),
         [Permission Path] nvarchar(128) )


INSERT INTO @UserList EXEC xp_logininfo @NTLogin, 'all' --insert group information

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @UserList WHERE [Type] = 'group') --only if it's a group
   INSERT INTO @UserList EXEC xp_logininfo @NTLogin, 'members' --insert member information

SELECT * FROM @UserList
```

Comment: This only works if the user/group is added as a login to the SQL instance, otherwise you will get no results.

Comment: @JasonCumberland yes, and IMHO this is how it should be indeed, after all, we are interested in what is happening within the sql server realm in this case, anything outside you can query the active directory using powershell.

Comment: I don't disagree, but I highly doubt that only looking at SQL logins is the limit of what OP is trying to accomplish.  Better to tell them to use PowerShell instead of this answer, IMHO.  Maybe as OP for clarification?